# Installing SteamCMD on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, steam

when I try to install SteamCMD on CentOS 7 I get an error: Login Failure: No Connection, I can confirm that selinux is disabled, and that the firewall is turned off, I can get it to work fine in CentOS 6, but for CentOS 7 there seems to be some sort of hiccup, any help would be appreciated, has anyone else tried to install SteamCMD on CentOS 7?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. A better place would be ServerFault.

Answer (score 8):

I did it on CentOs 7.

I created a separate user, downloaded the tar and extracted it as stated in official doc.

Double check your dependencies and your Firewall, the new firewall in centos 7 is called "firewalld".

So this is what I would try in your case (as root):

```
yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
systemctl stop firewalld
useradd steam
su - steam
wget http://media.steampowered.com/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
./steamcmd.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Manually

```
curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf -
```

worked for me